# How to change Container color choosing from list of Colors?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-html

I have a todo app, where i want color of text container, choosen while adding that task.
Task Container is on another screen and options to choose colors are onn another screen and im using Provider too for state management.

here is task container on one screen:

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          height: screenHeight * 0.1,
          width: screenWidth * 0.74,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue , // choosen color ill be here
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                blurRadius: 6,
                offset: Offset(-3, 3),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Text(
            widget.taskTile,
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: isDone ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
              decorationColor: Colors.black,
              decorationThickness: 3,
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodyText1.color,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

here are 4 circular container are options to choose color from:

```
    int _selectedIndex;
    Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter task' : null,
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: (val) {
                taskTitle = val;
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 70),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              chooseContainerColor(Colors.red, 0),
              chooseContainerColor(Colors.amberAccent, 1),
              chooseContainerColor(Colors.teal, 2),
              chooseContainerColor(Colors.blue, 3),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 60),
          FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            onPressed: () {
              addTask();
            },
            color: CustomColors().primaryColor,
            child: Text(
              'Add',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
         Widget chooseContainerColor(Color color, int index){
          return GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
          setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
           });
       },
     child: Container(
     height: 50,
      width: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       border: index == _selectedIndex ? Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black) :    Border.all(width: 0) ,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: color,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to create a Color variable. Each time you call onPressed, change the variable's value and call setState() to tell the widget to update the UI.
Declare the color as a variable:

```
Color containerColor=Colors.red;
```

In your onPressed():

```
setState(() {
  containerColor= Colors.teal;
});
```

In your Container's decoration:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: containerColor,
)
```